# WCF Implementation

Tags: wcf

I am designing the ERP Web Application. I would like to know the best approach for the WCF implementation. I have 2 design. can anybody help me which is best or tell me any other best approach for the same.

First Approach

```
  Web Server(Server-1)

      UI Layer(Web Application) - (Layer-1)
      UI Handler(Class Library) - (Layer-2)

  Web Service(Server-2)

      WCF Service (WCF Service Application)
      Contract Client(Class Library)
      Contract (Class Library)
      Biz Operation Layer (Class Library)
      DB Layer (Class Library)
      Biz Entity (Class Library)
```

Data Flow

UI -> UI handler ->  Web Service -> Contract Client -> Biz -> DB
Here Each Call is Binded to one Method in Each Layer.

Second Approach

```
  Web Server(Server-1)

      UI Layer(Web Application) - (Layer-1)
      UI Handler(Class Library) - (Layer-2)

  Web Service(Server-2)

      WCF Service (WCF Service Application)
      Biz Layer (Class Library)
      DB Layer (Class Library)
      Biz Entity (Class Library)
```

UI -> UI handler ->  Web Service -> Biz -> DB

Which is best or Is there anyother best approach available for WCF implementation.

Thanks in Advance.

Palanivelrajan

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335699.aspx